# Pythong imageio.v3 OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python, python-imageio

I am getting "**Python int too large to convert to C long**" when executing `out_file.init_video_stream("vp9", fps=fps)`

Maybe my video is to large is the cause of it? (vidoe info size: 146MB, 1920x960, total bitrate 4187kbps)

I am using python3.10 and imageio=2.29.0 + av=9.2.0

Here is the code:

```
path = "movie.mp4"
fps = iio.immeta(path, plugin="pyav")["fps"]

with iio.imopen(dest, "w", plugin="pyav") as out_file:
    out_file.init_video_stream("vp9", fps=fps)

    for frame in iio.imiter(path, plugin="pyav"):
        out_file.write_frame(frame)
```

Comment: it is the fps too many decimal